# Redirect to preview page adding Parameters

Tags: php, forms, redirect, parameters

is there a way to add parameters by redirecting to another page?
I redirect like this:

```
header( 'Location: http://pXXX.prtgX.pretago.de/wordpress/testseite-fuer-db/');
```

Is there a solution to add a parameter? Because I want to give a success message at the redirected page, that the form is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your message as get parameter into url

```
header('Location: http://pXXX.prtgX.pretago.de/wordpress/testseite-fuer-db/?message=success');
```